# how does %*[^\n] (scanf) ,works in c?

Tags: c, string, scanf

can someone explain me how `%*[^n]` works  ?I understand that if I use that like `scanf("%*[^\n]")` it should ignore all the input till it meets a newline character but what really happens when I try something like this 
`scanf(" %*[^\n],%10s",str)` str being a declared string ,i thought all the input after newline
including newline will get in to the string but when i try to print its its just prints invalid characters.

Comment: Do you know the effect of putting that space and the comma in the format specifier string?

Comment: Did you check the return value? It seems that since you first searched for a newline, the comma can’t match and therefore the call fails before the string is read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
scanf( "%*[^\n],%10s", str);
```

attempts to read *and discard* everything up to (but not including) the next newline, then attempts to match a comma, then reads up to 10 non-whitespace characters into `str`.

That’s not going to work, because if you read up to a newline, then the next character in the stream is going to be a newline, not a comma.  You’re likely getting a *matching failure*, and the contents of `str` are not getting updated.  Check the return value of `scanf` to see if you successfully read the number of the items you were expecting (in this case, 1).

You *probably* want

```
scanf( "%*[^\n]%10s", str ); // no comma in format string.
```

This will read and discard everything up to the next newline, then any whitespace will be skipped, and up to 10 non-whitespace characters will b3 read into `str`.

Comment: "This will read and discard everything up to the next newline" --> only if the first character is not `'\n'`.  In that case nothing is read, `'\n'` remains in `stdin` and `str` unwritten.

Comment: The string in the question had leading space on the format string